# Vectorize getting every nth element (but nth element is variable)

Tags: vectorization, octave

**How can I vectorize getting every nth element if the nth element is variable?**

I know about:

```
A = randi( 10, 10, 2 );
B = A(2:2:end, :);   % make another matrix (B) that contains every 2nd element
```

But my **nth variable changes.**
Here's a working *FOR* loop code based on the golden angle:

1) It converts the (golden angle) in degrees wanted into cell bit location for array.
2) Shift array by that given amount.
3) Places the 1st shifted cell wanted into a new array.

```
signal_used_L1 = [1:9](:).';
total_samples  = numel( signal_used_L1 );

for hh = 1 : length( signal_used_L1 )

  % PHI
    deg_to_shift = 137.5077 * hh;

  % convert degrees wanted into cell bits
    shift_sig_in_bits_L1 = total_samples * deg_to_shift / 360;

  % shift signal by given amount of cell bits
    shift_sig_L1 = circshift(  signal_used_L1(:).' ,             ...
                               [0, round(shift_sig_in_bits_L1)]  );    

  % create array with shifted cell bits
    sig_bit_built(1, hh) = shift_sig_L1(1, 1);
end
```

PS: I'm using Octave 4.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but I'd vectorise your code as follows:

```
  signal_used_L1 = [1:9](:).';
  total_samples  = numel( signal_used_L1 );

% PHI
  deg_to_shift = 137.5077  * [1:length( signal_used_L1 )];

% convert degrees wanted into cell bits
  shift_sig_in_bits_L1 = total_samples * deg_to_shift / 360;

% obtain "wrap-around" indices given above cell bits
  indices = mod( -round( shift_sig_in_bits_L1 ), total_samples ) + 1;

% create array with shifted cell bits
  signal_used_L1( indices )
```

Incidentally, I think you meant to do circshift with a negative shift though (i.e. move "n" places to the *right*). In which case the vectorised code above would be `mod( round...` rather than `mod( -round...`